# Access 2010 using stored procedure as record source

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, adodb, recordset

I am in the process of converting an ADP (SQL Server back end, Access front end) to an ACCDB (as ADPs are not supported in later versions of Access).  From what I gather, this requires reworking any forms with stored procedure recordsources.  All sources I've found on how to use a stored procedure as a recordsource use something like the approach below, but I am getting an error message any time I try to assign an ADODB recordset to a form: "3251 - Operation is not supported for this type of object."  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  (Error triggers on Forms!New_frm_DIV_Master_View.Form.Recordset = RS.)

```
Private Sub DivMasterView_Click()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'PROMPT FOR SCAR
Dim SCAR As String
SCAR = InputBox("Please enter a SCAR.")

'STOP IF NO SCAR ENTERED
If IsNull(SCAR) Or SCAR = "" Then Exit Sub

'STOP IF INVALID SCAR ENTERED
If IsNull(DLookup("[SCAR]", "dbo_Client Listing", "[SCAR] = '" & SCAR & "'")) Then
    MsgBox "SCAR not found."
    Exit Sub
End If
    
'OPEN FORM
DoCmd.OpenForm "NEW_frm_DIV_Master_View", , , , , acHidden
    
'SET UP CONNECTION
Dim WCDenialManagerConnection As New ADODB.Connection
WCDenialManagerConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=PS2PW601940;DSN=WCDenialManager2016;User Id = ACCOUNTS\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "'"
WCDenialManagerConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 0
WCDenialManagerConnection.Open

'SET UP STORED PROCEDURE COMMAND
Dim CMD As ADODB.Command
Set CMD = New ADODB.Command
Set CMD.ActiveConnection = WCDenialManagerConnection
CMD.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
CMD.CommandTimeout = 0
CMD.CommandText = "storproc_Client_Data_by_DIV"

'SET UP PARAMETER
Dim PRM As ADODB.Parameter
Set PRM = CMD.CreateParameter("@SCAR", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, SCAR)
CMD.Parameters.Append PRM

'SET UP RECORDSET
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset

'EXECUTE COMMAND AND SET RECORDSET
Set RS = CMD.Execute
Forms!New_frm_DIV_Master_View.Form.Recordset = RS

'SHOW FORM
Forms!New_frm_DIV_Master_View.Form.Visible = True

'CLEANUP
CMD.Parameters.Delete "@SCAR"
Set PRM = Nothing
Set CMD = Nothing
WCDenialManagerConnection.Close
Set WCDenialManagerConnection = Nothing

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you just need a `Set`:  `Set Forms!New_frm_DIV_Master_View.Form.Recordset = RS`.

Comment: Well, that changed the error message, at least: "7965 - The object you entered is not a valid Recordset property."

Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Got it: Adding this to the connection setup fixed it: WCDenialManagerConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient